# Changing element p with input text field issue jquery

Tags: jquery

I am facing small issue while firing jquery event to replace element p or span with text field and onblur event replace back to p or span field.

Demo is here http://jsfiddle.net/yXcZG/

It works well for first time while clicking on p text, but failed when you repeat same process second time.

Can any one help me where should be the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jQueries .on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) selecor is used to attach to dynamic content, eg ajax and what you are doing. Normally you would just use `$('.myClass').click(funcction(){});`  but using a static class like you have done `$('.cmtedit').on(...` is problematic because once you clicked that class and it gets removed.. it no longer exists with the reference you created it with. So to use `.on` properly, you neeed to attach it to the `document` so it can always re attach to any dynamic content! :-)

> .on( events [, selector] [, data] , handler(eventObject) )

```
$(document).on('click', '.cmtedit', function (e) {
    console.log(this);
   TBox(this);
});
```

Works well here..

http://jsfiddle.net/yXcZG/3/

Also remember to remove `console.log();` if you are not usin Chrome or Firefox. It is not supported in IE at all!

Answer (score 0):

I think as you are removing the obj by doing

```
 $(obj).remove();
```

in the `TBox` function

so in the `RBox` function when you create it again you have to add click event handler

OR even better

I suggest you use

```
$(".cmtedit").live('click', function (e) {
```

instead of

```
$(".cmtedit").on('click', function (e) {
```

for reference  http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: remove(); will delete previous element after change happen, if you remove this line, then this happen. http://jsfiddle.net/yXcZG/4/, i don't know when i use .on instead of .live with 'blur' event it failed.

Comment: dont remove that line....just change the first line... as I have suggested in later part of the answer

Answer (score 0):

You are not attaching the click event to the new <p> created in the RBox() function. The following code works: (Test if out here: http://jsfiddle.net/yXcZG/5/)

```
$(".cmtedit").on('click', function (e) {
   TBox(this);
});

$("input").live('blur', function (e) {
   RBox(this);
});
function TBox(obj) {
        var id = $(obj).attr("id");

        var tid = id.replace("cmt_edit_", "cmt_tedit_");
        var input = $('<input />', { 'type': 'text', 'name': 'n' + tid, 'id': tid, 'class': 'text_box', 'value': $(obj).html() });
        $(obj).parent().append(input);
        $(obj).remove();
        input.focus();
}
function RBox(obj) {
    var id = $(obj).attr("id");

    var tid = id.replace("cmt_tedit_", "cmt_edit_");
    var input = $('<p />', { 'id': tid, 'class': 'cmtedit', 'html': $(obj).val() });
    $(obj).parent().append(input);
    $(obj).remove();

    $(".cmtedit").on('click', function (e) {
     TBox(this);
   });
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you though I would refactor it (live is expensive) and write it like this:

```
<style>
    ​#cmt_edit_323 input { display: none; }​
</style>

<div id="sample">
     <p id="cmt_edit_323" class="cmtedit"><span>Sample Text</span><input type="text"></input>    </p>
</div>​​​​​

<script>
$(".cmtedit").on('click', function (e) {
   TBox(this);
});

$(".cmtedit input").on('blur', function (e) {
   RBox(this);
});

function TBox(obj) {
        var input = $(obj).find("input");
        var span = $(obj).find("span");
        input.attr('value', span.text()).show().focus();
        span.hide();            

}
function RBox(obj) {
        var input = $(obj);
        var span = $(obj).parent().find("span");
        span.html(input.attr('value')).show();
        input.hide();
}​
</script>
```

Check it here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yXcZG/6/)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't make comment so I had to make it as an answer.

@ppumkin's answer was working with just a small issue - if you click out of the browser or switch tabs, two elements were added inside the parent.

I tried to check many other events to resolve this but with no luck.
So the easiest solution for me was to do a simple check before append the element in the `RBox()` function:

```
if ($("#" + tid).length == 0) {
    $(obj).parent().append(input);
}
```

Apart from this I used [**.on()**](https://api.jquery.com/on/) method for the `blur` as **[.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)** is deprecated and no longer recommended.